# How to pass hidden value to link in grails

Tags: grails

I have the following code.

```
<li><g:link controller="page" action="viewPage" params="[id:selectedId]">
Click here</g:link></li>
```

I have one hidden field.

```
<g:hiddenField name="selectedId" value="1234"/>
```

Now When i click on link i want the value of hidden field in viewPage Action. 
I have tried a lot but i can't find anyway.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Where does the value of the hidden field come from? If it comes from a controller, use grails to put it in to `params` otherwise you have to use javascript and modify the link.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit, I don't mean to be a smartass but you do know that the hidden field must be inside your g:form?

Comment: Hi hidden field value comes from javascript. how can i set it in g:link.

Comment: yes marko my hidden field is inside the form.

Comment: Why do you need it in the link? If it is in the form you could submit the whole form to your desired action...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get hiddenfield value to g:link params.
I have create a link and use it's onclick event in which i am calling javascript function and from javascript function i am calling my grails request for viewPage.

```
<g:link class="heirarachyMenuItemPopup" onclick="return validateAndUpdateID()">
Click here</g:link>
```